# Why 2 backslashes are needed to escape a backslash in vim -c argument?

Tags: bash, git, shell, vim

In Windows 10, I used following command in Git bash 1.9.5,

```
$ vim -c "%s/^/\=line(".").'. '/g" -c "%s/\//\\/g" -c "%y+" -c "wq" ~/Desktop/sample.txt
```

in order to,

1. `-c "%s/^/\=line(".").'. '/g"`: add a sequence of numbers before every line.
2. `-c "%s/\//\\/g"`: replace all slashes with backslashes.
3. `-c "%y+" -c "wq"`: copy all text to clipboard, save & exit Vim.

Everything works well except `2`, it seems that `-c "%s/\//\\/g"` argument cannot be dealt correctly by Vim. None of slashes was replaced, and a `g` was inserted after every first `/` of each line. For example,

> #### Sample.txt before
>
> A/P/A/T/H
> B/P/A/T/H

> #### Sample.txt after
>
> A/**g**P/A/T/H
> B/**g**P/A/T/H

However, if I execute `:%s/\//\\/g` in vim, it would works as I expected.

Besides, I've tried these,

- `-c "%s/\//@/g"` can replace all `/` to `@` as expected.
- `-c "%s,/,\\,g"` will replace the first `/` in each line to `,g`.

So, I wonder if it is a limit or a known issue of `-c` argument, or I made mistakes somewhere?

**Edit**: I just found by chance that `-c "%s/\//\\\/g"` works as expected.
So could anyone please explain why another `\` is needed to escape `\`?

Comment: Note that this has nothing at all to do with Git, and not much to do with vim either. As [romainl explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65904928/1256452), the issue here is in your *shell*. ("Git bash" is a port of bash to Windows, and not part of Git itself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vim, when using regular expressions, the backslash is used to escape characters so it can't be used on its own to represent a literal backslash. For that, you must escape the literal backslash with an escape backslash:

```
:%s/\//\\/g
```

So you start with **two** backslashes no matter what: the escape one and the literal one. That's what Vim expects.

In your shell, backslashes also have a special meaning. When inside double quotes, two consecutive backslashes "collapse" into a single one so, when you think you are telling Vim to do:

```
:%s/\//\\/g
```

with:

```
-c "%s/\//\\/g"
```

what it actually receives is:

```
%s/\//\/g
```

which means: "substitute each slash with an escaped slash (so a simple slash) followed by letter g". Not exactly what you had in mind.

To make sure Vim actually receives the proper command you need to add a **third** backslash:

```
-c "%s/\//\\\/g"
```

Two backslashes are collapsed into a single one and the other one is left intact so you end up with **two** backslashes, which is what Vim expects:

```
%s/\//\\/g
```

Another, *better*, approach would be to use single quotes, where backslashes are always literal, instead of double quotes:

```
-c '%s/\//\\/g'
```

[From this page about shell quoting](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html), emphasis mine:

> The backslash retains its meaning only when followed by dollar, backtick, double quote, *backslash* or newline. *Within double quotes, the backslashes are removed from the input stream when followed by one of these characters*.

Comment: Now that was unexpected. Thank you!